# stackstatus.net SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Tags: bug, status-declined, stackstatus

Apparently stackstatus.net is being served over https using the tumblr certificated instead of it's own domain. I presume there should have its own certificated.

Comment: What do you mean by "there should have its own certificated"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen change "there" for "here", it's an indicative of place. I presume *in that place it* should have its own certificated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tumblr does not support SSL certificates on custom domains:

> You're currently using a custom domain name ("stackstatus.net"). That's cool, but we're not currently able to serve custom domains over SSL.

Given that this domain needs to stay 100% seperate from our existing infrastructure, there's no easy way for us to enable SSL for this domain at the moment.

We can't even [go behind CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168566-How-do-I-add-a-Tumblr-custom-domain-) for this unfortunately. We will evaluate alternatives in the future.

Comment: Oh well, at least we tried :(

Comment: Would you mind enabling your diamond on MSE? I find it highly confusing when *ordinary* users answer these questions that accurate AND slam the status-declined on the question....

Comment: Mark's been around here for years, @rene. Many adjectives have been used to describe him, and many adjectives fit... but I don't know that "ordinary" is among them.

Comment: @rene as Shog alluded to, it's not my decision whether I get a diamond on MSE. The only reason I have one on serverfault.com is because I was an elected moderator there before I started working for Stack. The quick hover-over on my display profile should hopefully clear things up for anyone else who is confused in the future.

Comment: @MarkHenderson yeah, I have had a few words with him in chat and I rest my case. Thanks for being on the team!

Comment: Note: as of the changes to the StackStatus website last year (as described in [Improvements to site status and incident communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378941/335251)), the site is no longer hosted on Tumblr, and now uses HTTPS.