# Many API requests to /questions with filter parameters are failing with status code 400 errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

For some questions, using a `filter` parameter appears to break the API, causing it to return a "400 Bad Request" status code with the following payload:

```json
{"error_id":404,"error_message":"no method found with this name","error_name":"no_method"}
```

Examples

- [Broken](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72303483?site=stackoverflow.com&filter=!b0OfMvgVcFN2Ro&key=ZCNbdLB0bpKnf4EjSy8bdQ((): `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72303483?site=stackoverflow.com&filter=!b0OfMvgVcFN2Ro&key=ZCNbdLB0bpKnf4EjSy8bdQ((`
- [Working](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72356719?site=stackoverflow.com&filter=!b0OfMvgVcFN2Ro&key=ZCNbdLB0bpKnf4EjSy8bdQ((): `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72356719?site=stackoverflow.com&filter=!b0OfMvgVcFN2Ro&key=ZCNbdLB0bpKnf4EjSy8bdQ((` (same as broken, different question).
- [Working](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72303483?site=stackoverflow.com&key=ZCNbdLB0bpKnf4EjSy8bdQ((): `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72303483?site=stackoverflow.com&key=ZCNbdLB0bpKnf4EjSy8bdQ((` (same as broken, no filter)

This is breaking many userscripts, and according to one report, the SE iOS app.

Comment: In the iOS app, many sites are still working but Meta.SE doesn't.

Comment: MSE, MSO and Meta MathOverflow (at minimum) aren't available in the iOS App. Other meta and main sites seem fine.

Comment: I'm seeing `400 Bad Request` in addition to 404.  The Unclosed Request Review Script gets a 400 when requesting something like `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/72357743;72351987;42650412;7380828;72254536;72303483;72166432;72271052;5837077;72174614;72347339;72357457;72334967;72356829;72357188;37560979;72058205;44052754?pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&key=YvvkfBc3LOSK*mwaTPkUVQ((&filter=!m)9LJxKwexI9h92EPpSH6vR(2S7pz3L9cXWiH9ar04WP8BSWy0Mtyl7P` although I get a 404 when I visit that URL afterwards.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have corrected the post; it's a "400 Bad Request" status code, but the JSON payload has an `error_id` of `404`.

Comment: Ah, HTTP status doesn't match status reported in payload.

Comment: I'll be looking into it. If there are new examples of different kinds of queries not working (different from what is already posted) please add them here as well.

Comment: @YaakovEllis so see my Q posted with the update about "newest" and "active". https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/643/10902

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that this is fixed. Issue was that we forgot to deploy new code for the API, and as a result, some API queries included meta-data about some posts that the old deployed code did not know how to process (resulting in the errors). New deploy seems to have solved this (if you still see any errors, please leave them as comments here).

More details: we are in the middle of switching our deployment tools (from Team City to CircleCI/Octopus, for those who are interested), and (obviously) still need to sort out and optimize some things with our workflow to ensure that missed-deployments like this don't happen. Apologies for the inconvenience.

> API `GET` Error!
> Old code still live, needs refresh…
> New deploy fixed it.

Comment: Team City is broken, or is this violation of "If it ain't broken, don't fix it" mantra? :)

Comment: Team City isn't broken, but not being broken isn't the same as "meets all of our needs". That said, I am not on the team who is working on deployments, and thus can't give any more information on the different factors at play here. Hopefully we can post about it in the future.

Comment: Re my comment and linked post, all working fine between "active" and "newest". Cheers.

Comment: Well, nothing is perfect, but I do trust your deployment people that they had good reason to make the switch. Hopefully, it would go smoothly.